Artifacts when rendering volumetrics
When making a scene with volumetrics in cycles (blender 4.2.3)I've run into an unexpected problem.
Almost every time I render (or almost every frame when I want to render an animation) I get these weird horizontal lines spreading from one end of the picture to the other. From what I understand, they appear pretty randomly: random place, random time, random sample when rendering.
I have done quite a lot to try to resolve the issue: updated the gpu drivers, tried changing the light paths in a number of ways, changed the max samples, tried both CUDA and OptiX, checked the denoiser, tried tiling when rendering (when I did that, the lines were from one end of the tile to the other, not the entire image), changed the feature set to experimental. I even tried making a test file with nothing but a cube with a principled volume shader, and I still got the same artifacts. Without the volumetrics, everything works just as it should (at least I think so).
I am running an RTX 2080ti with a ryzen 5 5600X. When rendering, my GPU memory doesn't exceed 30-40%, so I don't think that the issue is there either. The temperature also remains under 60-70 degrees celsius (which is not bad considering how bad my PC cooling is).
These artifacts show only in blender 4.2.3 LTS, when I tried the same file in 4.0 nothing was out of the ordinary (but the results were underwhelming, because of the older cycles version).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.



Cycles haven't change much (at all ?) recently, maybe try using 4.1 or 4.0 instead ? Sharing your file would also help so that we can see if there is an issue inside it : https://blend-exchange.com/

I think that it has, since the scene looks brighter in the 4.2.3 LTS than in 4.1. This is the link for the file and more screenshots: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KNLMXHJF8KKKaPksOmOigiKUtSoB9WgH?usp=sharing

As far as I can tell, there has been new features but no changes on the engine itself, release notes of 4.2 : https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.2/cycles/. I'm not getting any artifacts with your file, maybe try updating your GPU ? Do you also get artifacts with the denoiser disabled ?

I updated the drivers and it's not the denoiser. It's quite insteresting why it worked on your machine. I was thinking, that it just might be my GPU, but then why would it work on earlier versions? Thanks for the replies so far :)
